# Select hourly data based on days

Tags: python, pandas, filter, time-series, selection

I have a time series `hourly_df`, containing some hourly data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

hourly_index = pd.date_range(start='2018-01-01', end='2018-01-07', freq='H')
hourly_data = np.random.rand(hourly_index.shape[0])
hourly_df = pd.DataFrame(hourly_data, index=hourly_index)
```

and I have a DatetimeIndex, containing some dates (as days as I wish), e.g.

```
daily_index = pd.to_datetime(['2018-01-01', '2018-01-05', '2018-01-06'])
```

I want to select each row of `hourly_df`, which date of its index is in `daily_index`, so in my case all hourly data from 1st, 5th and 6th January. What is the best way to do this?

If I naively use `hourly_df.loc[daily_index]`, I only get the rows at 0:00:00 for each of the three days. What I want is the hourly data for the whole day for each of the days in `daily_index`.

One possibility to solve this, is to create a filter that takes the date of each element in the index of `hourly_df` and compares whether of not this date is in `daily_index`.

```
day_filter = [hour.date() in daily_index.date for hour in hourly_df.index]
hourly_df[day_filter]
```

This produces the desired output, but it seems the usage of the filter is avoidable and can be done in an expression similar to `hourly_df.loc[daily_index.date]`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. save the `daily_index` as a `dataframe`
2. merge on index using `hourly_df.merge(daily_index, how = 'inner', ...)`